# Iptables list doesn't persist across restarts

Tags: centos, iptables, whitelist, cloudflare

I am trying to white list CloudFlare's IP addresses on my server by issuing these:

```
iptables -N whitelist
iptables -A whitelist -s 204.93.177.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A whitelist -s 199.27.128.0/21 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A whitelist -s 173.245.48.0/20 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A whitelist -s 103.22.200.0/22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A whitelist -s 141.101.64.0/18 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A whitelist -s 108.162.192.0/18 -j ACCEPT
```

and when I type: `iptables -L` I see:

```
Chain whitelist (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  network/24           anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  199.27.128.0/21      anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  173.245.48.0/20      anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  103.22.200.0/22      anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  141.101.64.0/18      anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  108.162.192.0/18     anywhere
```

then I restart iptables by doing `service iptables restart`. However, nothing changed and it didn't white list those IPs :( Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you referencing the `whitelist` chain from anywhere?  What's your `INPUT` chain look like?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to save the configuration before restarting.  On Redhat systems, this goes in /etc/sysconfig/iptables.  The easiest way to do this is:

- Issue your commands
- run `iptables -L` to check the config
- run `service iptables save`
- run `service iptables restart` to reload
- check the config again with `iptables -L`